# Compile mex files for spm12 in Matlab r2012a student version

Tags: compiling, gcc, matlab

in 2012 I bought a student version of Matlab (r2012a, 32bit) which I have now installed on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. This far, everything works.

However, I would like to install SPM12 (a software used for analysing functional neuroimaging (and other) data, for which I need to compile certain mex-files. According to the install instructions accessible [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Linux#Installation), I need to run a number of commands, like this

```
cd /home/login/spm12/src
make distclean
make && make install
make external-distclean
make external && make external-install
```

Yet, while changing drive (obviously) and make distclean seem to run without problems, I get a couple of warnings when running make && make install, which look like this:

```
mex -O -largeArrayDims -c spm_vol_utils.c -DSPM_UNSIGNED_CHAR 

Warning: You are using gcc version "4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.4.6".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

mv -f spm_vol_utils.o  utils_uchar.mexa64.o
```

I get about fifteen of these warnings (apparently for various mex files to be compiled). As it appears, I would need to use gcc version 4.4.6 in order to compile these files, but searching for help online has not brought any success, neither running sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4

Any suggestions as to how I could compile these files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so five more minutes of searching might have helped me to find an answer. 
[Here](http://shuiqingwang.blogspot.de/2012/07/downgrade-gcc-to-446-on-ubuntu-1110-64.html) is an explanation of how to set gcc to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure the files failed to compile? Warnings are usually just that (warnings, not errors).

If you do want to compile with gcc-4.4.x, it is however still available from the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, as package `gcc-4.4` (although at least in 14.04.2 it appears to be minor version 4.4.7 rather than 4.4.6). You should be able to install it via the Software Center (or synaptic package manager, if it is installed) or from the command line using

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

Unless you symlink the binary to make it the system's default compiler (which I would **not** recommend), you will probably need to modify your `mexopts.sh` file to point directly to gcc-4.4 i.e.

```
CC='gcc-4.4'
```

An identical process can be used for g++ if your files need it i.e. install `g++-4.4` and set `CXX='g++-4.4'` in `mexopts.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to modify my mexopts.sh file in the way you specified and as pointed out somewhere else, which unfortunately did not work. Therefore I followed the instructions I found [here](http://shuiqingwang.blogspot.de/2012/07/downgrade-gcc-to-446-on-ubuntu-1110-64.html). Somehow I have the strange feeling that this proceeding is exactly the one you do **not** recommend.